# Can we have customized, verbose, descriptive "automatically move this discussion to chat" messages?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, conversation

### tl;dr for the tl;dr:

Replace current "move to chat" message with a longer one, custom-tailored for the question owner, answer owner, or third-party-participant as may be the case.

### tl;dr:

Attempt to clarify the move-to-chat message that appears when two people start a conversation.

1. Replacing "discussion" by "conversation", as there aren't solely discussions and [to avoid confusion](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2802/please-avoid-extended-discussions-in-comments).
2. Guide the community that questions & answers should be improved [instead of having conversations which hide details](https://superuser.com/questions/302486/custom-nvidia-resolutions/302498#302498), alongsite other useful guidelines regarding flagging/disagreement/...
3. See the proposed quotes, what do you think? How to decrease their length? Any improvements?

---

### Feature request:

> ORIGINAL: Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

**Not all comment threads are discussions**, I want to propose using `conversation` instead.

Example: [Custom NVIDIA Resolutions?](https://superuser.com/questions/302486/custom-nvidia-resolutions/302498#302498)

Reasoning for these proposals:

- A comment is a remark expressing an opinion or reaction on a question or answer.
- Comment threads aren't meant for chatting, conversations and discussion.
- It could be a conversation where the questioner is replying back-and-forth on either comment or answer to resolve his problem. While instead the question or answer should be improved...
- The current message [is *really confusing* to people](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2802/please-avoid-extended-discussions-in-comments) who aren't discussing, making this more general along with guidelines would greatly guide the community in using comment threads right and will discourage any form of extended conversations in comment threads as they are less useful.

---

### In question comment threads:

**For the question owner**; I want to propose to change this message to:

> Would you like to [automatically move this conversation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/just-an-example-link) to our chat? Please avoid conversations in comments. If your problem is unresolved, improve your question. If you disagree with changes to your question, use the flag link or start a meta discussion.

Reasoning:

- This encourages more information in the question, instead of hidden away in comments.
- This discourages additional questions in the comments, as well as arguing about closes/edits.

**For an answerer**; I want to propose to change this message to:

> Would you like to [automatically move this conversation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/just-an-example-link) to our chat? Please avoid conversations in comments. If you have more information, you can add an answer or improve an existing answer. If the question can't be reasonably answered, use the flag link or start a meta discussion.

Reasoning:

- This encourage to give an answer instead of resolving the problem in the comment thread.
- This discourages arguing about closes/edits, as well as to keep asking additional information. In which case a question should more likely be closed as "not a real question" as it is incomplete...

---

### In answer comment threads:

**For the question owner**, I want to propose to change this message to:

> Would you like to [automatically move this conversation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/just-an-example-link) to our chat? Please avoid conversations in comments. If your question is unanswered, improve your question. Ask a new question if you have a different problem.

Reasoning:

- This encourages to improve the question so everyone is aware that it's still unresolved, or ask a new question if the questioner has another relevant problem.
- This discourages the final suggestion from being hidden away in a comment thread.

**For an answer owner**, I want to propose to change this message to:

> Would you like to [automatically move this conversation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/just-an-example-link) to our chat? Please avoid conversations in comments. If you have more information, you can improve your answer. Avoid extended discussions, voting will tell if the answer was useful.

Reasoning:

- This encourages to improve the answer so that everyone is aware of additional information relevant to the problem and solution, instead of hidden away in the comments.
- This discourages extended discussions, where the owner is trying to defend his answer

**For another answerer**, I want to propose to change this massage to:

> Would you like to [automatically move this conversation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/just-an-example-link) to our chat? Please avoid conversations in comments. If you have more information to add, improve the answer or create your own answer. Avoid extended discussions, voting will tell if the answer was useful.

- This encourages to improve the answer or come up with an own solution, instead of having a solution hidden away in the comments.
- This discourages extended discussions, where the answerer tries to disproof the answer.

---

**What do you think? Feel free to suggest improvements for cases I've missed...**

Comment: @TomWij: Like the idea (pretty much what I was suggesting...), don't like the suggested message (three lines is too long).

Comment: **Does anyone have an idea how we could shorten them?** Perhaps one of the lines in each comment is less necessary than the other lines. It's slightly longer than a close reason and only shows for people that start a conversation with each other in a short period of time. So I believe by being a sentence shorter they would be fine. Given that the close reasons hold a lot of information, I believe shorter version of my proposals can be made too. *Secretly pointing at the brief description specialist in the Stack Exchange team...*

Comment: Can you not come someway between tl;dr and the long, long post?

Comment: @Random: Thanks! Adjusted, spent some time on the post so I prematurely posted it with a bad TL;DR. :(

Comment: Hmm.. I don't know whether I should vote for this. I like the proposed changes, but I hate the original feature they're proposing to change. :sigh:

Comment: Discussions are conversations and vice-versa.  Discussions are conversations about things.  Conversations are talking, and if you're not talking about things then you're making random noises/scribbles/keypresses.  Who could possibly be confused by "discussion"?  The confusion you link to is *entirely* unrelated to the choice of word there.

Comment: @MatthewRead: **Discussion lies an explicit focus on... Discussion.** And if I'm talking to a friend I'm not discussing, but I'm just having a conversation; whether that conversation is a discussion depends on what we are talking about. **A discussion is a conversation about a choice, not a thing.** Check the definition: `an act or instance of discussing;  consideration or examination by argument, comment, etc., especially to explore solutions; informal debate.`

Comment: If you are using [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discussion) instead of [Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discussion), make sure that you actually read the merged page which says that a discussion is a classification of a conversation and is listed as following: `Discussion where conversants compare, contrast and evaluate the conversants' respective ideas, without an opinion or position as to the correctness of any idea.`

Answer (score 7):

I like these suggestions -- I like solutions that take effect "Just In Time" and with contextual information about the user's intentions. But I have some concerns:

- it's a bit wordy.
- it may be overly complex, as in perhaps we are overthinking this?
- I am not entirely convinced that

  > Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

  is at all confusing to anyone.

Comment: (1) I've cut them down in length by removing not really useful words/sentences, and rewriting sentences. They should be less wordy now. (2) They might be slightly less complex now because of the edit. We should be looking into some examples (perhaps they can be fetched with a SQL query *where 2 people have more than 3 comments*) to see whether they apply for each case, although I think they handle a lot of cases. I don't know if they are over-thought, checking it against a sample can tell us if this is of great benefit or just over-thought.

Comment: (3) [The example from which this idea originated](http://superuser.com/questions/302486/custom-nvidia-resolutions/302498#302498) isn't a discussion, Mehrdad questions for more information which Mokubai gives spread over two comments. Mehrdad provides more information about his system. Mokubai explains even more information. They aren't really discussing about something, they are rather providing information to each other which could be edited into Q&A. In this case, which I believe does happen more, this comment doesn't make sense as there is no discussion.

Comment: Going through the top month questions: [Other example, imagine him asking yet another detail](http://superuser.com/questions/297702/what-do-the-parentheses-and-number-after-a-linux-command-or-c-function-mean/297706#297706), not a discussion and can be included in the answer. [Here is an example of an OP](http://superuser.com/questions/291687/is-it-possible-to-run-windows-without-gui/291694#291694) giving more information in the comments of an answer, getting to his solution in the comments; not a discussion.

Comment: [I'm guilty myself](http://superuser.com/questions/300929/what-means-do-i-have-to-catch-a-hacker-that-cracked-in-one-of-my-computers/301054#301054), commenting with the OP to a solution; not a discussion ignoring the last 2 comments. While I had to explicitly ask him to update his question, and to be strictly correct and have an acceptable answer I should outline the details I gave in the comments into my answer, whether or not they solved the problem.

Comment: @TomWij: Four comments in a row? **Would you like to (manually) move this discussion to chat?**

Comment: @Mehrdad: I assume this is sarcastic? This is an extended remark to reflect Jeff Atwood's answer, this is not a discussion nor a conversation. Now, the next step could be that Jeff Atwood updates his answer to reflect my comments, or he does nothing at all. But there is no point in him replying here as he might as well take me to the chat. But your comment actually starts a conversation so I'm not going to say anymore than this to you. If you want to reply, find me in [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) or invite me to a new room...

Comment: @TomWij: I think you took my comment too seriously in one direction, and not seriously enough in another. ;) It was meant to poke some fun at the fact that you were having a conversation with yourself, while demonstrating the point that the message gets annoying sometimes.

Comment: I think it's good if the chat is attached to the question or an answer, and it's not going anywhere or hard to find in future.  If people think it's just like a regular main chat room then they might think it'll be lost and not be keen to do it and prefer to stick with comments. There could be a very brief line about taking discussion to chat, and a FAQ for more info about chat in connection with comments e.g. mentioning that it's not a main room, and it's available for reference at this permanent link.