# What is the point of "automatically move these comments to chat" when it never works?

Tags: support, comments, chat

I  sometimes see this message

[image]

It **never** works. I click that and comments are *copied* into chat, or referred to in chat. They are never moved. The only time they are actually moved is if a moderator moves them (or deletes them and they're preserved in chat).

What is the point of a message that clearly and obviously isn't doing what it says?  We are computer people and we know the difference between copy and move. It's not really a move when the thing still exists at the source. So it's not moving from comments to chat, is it?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96493/can-we-have-customized-verbose-descriptive-automatically-move-this-discussion

Comment: @HackerKarma Hardly. There are going to be many questions  related to that message. But I haven't found any that actually question the fact that the comments are not moved but are copied.

Comment: It kinda related but not a dupe. Your question is about "move" vs "copy".  +1 for that

Comment: It says "automatically move this **discussion**" (ie subsequent comments) **not** "move the comments".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> We are computer people and we know the difference between copy and move.

If you want to argue technicalities, where in your screenshot does it say anything about moving *comments*?

The point is not moving the *comments* to chat (although we have debated whether or not to automatically delete the comments that are imported into chat).

As the message says, the point is to move the *discussion* to chat – stop discussing in comments, start discussing in chat. Which is also why the automatically posted comment says "Let us continue this discussion in chat".

The reason for importing the previous comments as messages into chat is mainly to help kickstart this relocation.

Comment: I don't think we want automatic deletion (that can be weaponized), but it'd be nice if an automatic flag could be raised when this happens so mods can review and (usually) delete the comments.